# Classe PDO não encontrada em namespace diferente do global

Tags: php, pdo, composer, namespace, php-autoload

Estou criando uma classe que utiliza PDO, porém em um namespace diferente do global:

```
namespace Classes\Config;

use \PDO;

class Connection {
    public static function getConnection() {
        $dbhost = "algumhost";
        $dbuser = "algumuser";
        $dbpass = "algumasenha";
        $dbname = "algumabase";
        $dbms = "algumsgbd";
        $dbport = "9999";
        $dsn = "$dbms:host=$dbhost;port=$dbport;dbname=$dbname;user=$dbuser;password=$dbpass";
        try {
            $dblink = new PDO ( $dsn );
            $dblink->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
            echo 'Erro na conexão: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $dblink;
    }
}
```

Após tentar usar o método getConnecton, acabo obtendo esse erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Classes\PDO' not found in path/para/meuarquivo.php on line 69
```

Alguem sabe o que posso estar fazendo de errado? Desde já agradeço.

P.S: Utilizo o composer para fazer o autoload do meu projeto.

Informações do PDO no phpinfo():
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sei se interfere em algo, mas já tenou tirar a barra invertida, fazendo apenas `use PDO;`?

Comment: Já tentei tbm. Antes de postar minha pergunta, vi algumas postagens sobre, mas não interferiu no resultado

Comment: Exatamente a mesma mensagem de erro? PHP buscando a classe PDO no namespace `Classes`?

Comment: Exatamente.... :/

Comment: Porque não utiliza a classe diretamente: `new \PDO()` ? Até onde eu entendo, não é possível importar as classes do namespace \ diretamente. Mas isso também não faz sentido, já que você pode apenas colocar a primeira barra na frente.

Comment: Mesmo utilizando a barra no `new \PDO()` o php não consegue encontrar a classe no namespace global

Comment: @CesarAndré, neste caso, é provavel que esteja faltando alguma extensão. Qual a versão do seu php? E o sistema operacional?

Comment: @jlHertel PHP 5.6.14 e Windows 7

Comment: @CesarAndré, poderia verificar a saída do comando phpinfo(). Existe alguma seção falando do PDO? Caso sim, quais drivers foram carregados?

Comment: @jlHertel http://imgur.com/a/tnMdm

Comment: @CesarAndré, não possuo acesso ao imgur. Poderia atualizar seu post com a imagem, ou somente responder as perguntas?

Comment: @CesarAndré, poderia postar o erro que você recebeu ao usar a sintaxe `new \PDO()` ?

Comment: é o mesmo erro que eu coloquei na pergunta

Comment: Não é apenas `new \PDO`. Existem também as constantes `\PDO::ATTR_ERRMOD` e `\PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, e a exception `\PDOException`. Acostume-se a usar contrabarra para tudo que é global.

Comment: Além do mais, seu erro aparece `Classes\PDO` e o namespace do arquivo em questão é `Classes\Config`. Seu problema está em outro lugar.

Comment: @CesarAndré, o Gabriel tem razão. O erro não pode ser o mesmo, pois você mudou o namespace. Por favor, atualize a pergunta com o comando que você tentou juntamente com o erro recebido.